# Change content after being loaded by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to change the style of a certain element after loading.
However it gives me a null pointer.

```
function loadFriends() {
    $("#friendsContainer").load("friends.html");
}

selectCurrentSetting();

function selectCurrentSetting() {
    console.info("test");
    var selection = document.getElementById("friendsContainer").getAttribute("selection");
    console.info(selection);
    if (selection != null) {
        document.getElementById(selection).classList.add("selected");
    }
}
```

this is what it load in `friends.html`

```
<div id="friends" class="container friends_container">
    <div class="container_content" id="container_content">
        <div class="option" id="#profile" onclick="">Profile <span class="fas fa-cog icon"></span></div>
        <div class="option" id="#settings" onclick="">Settings <span class="fas fa-cog icon"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is what it should replace

```
<div id="friendsContainer" selection="settings"></div>
```

The code `selectCurrentSetting()` should change the style of `#settings` in `friends.html` after it gets loaded in.
However it gets me a null pointer.
[image: error I get in console]

How would I get it to execute the code in `selectCurrentSetting()` after the elements needed are available?

Comment: selection is referencing `var selection` which has a tested value of `settings` I've tried it with puttin in `"settings"` but got the same result.

Comment: Then remove # in id="#settings" or set selection="#settings" https://jsfiddle.net/020e2qzy/1/

Comment: Well, Such a simple mistake ;) But that's it! Thank you verry much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove # in

```
id="#settings"
```

or set

```
selection="#settings"
```

as you don't need # in your markup to set the id

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/020e2qzy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
   function loadFriends() {
      $("#friendsContainer").load("friends.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
          if (statusTxt == "success")
              selectCurrentSetting();
          if (statusTxt == "error")
              console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Updated, use `load` callback function which notify that content is loaded or not then perform dom manipulation.